# Ejecutar script de MySQL en Integration Services (SSIS)

Tags: mysql, sql, ssis

¿Es posible ejecutar script de MySQL en un ETL SSIS?. Comprendo que hay conectores que me permiten hacer conexiones a tablas para funciones de inserción, pero Integration Services me permitiría ir más allá por?, por ejemplo: Desde un task script requiero la creación de tablas temporales, updates, operaciones, procedimientos almacenados, etc.

Comment: Si, es posible, existen tareas de ejecución de scripts en SSIS, solamente debes hacer un linked server hacia MySQL en tu servidor y luego ejecutar tu script usando OPENQUERY dentro de una tarea de SSIS.

Comment: Es probable que sí. He usado SSIS para hacer consultas e insertar en Oracle, por lo que debe de funcionar en cualquier RDBMS que tenga un driver adecuado. Lo mejor es que lo intentes y también pruebes el rendimiento.